# Changing a text and setting a cursor in the input

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have an input that contains a text. When I click into this input, so the color of the text will change. In the input is eg. the text 'Hello buddy' - and when I click into the input in the end of the word `Hello`, so exist any easy way to set the cursor on the start (before the word `Hello`)?

```
$('#your_name').focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title')){
        $(this).css('color', 'red');
    }

    $(this).keyup(function() {
      $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

And when I start to type a text into the, how can I remove the current text `Hello buddy` and have in the input only the "new" text? I am trying to do with `keyup` method, but everything what I type is deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UbshP/3/) here. Also modified your jsFiddle.. see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/N9agf/6/)

**Edit**: You can just use `el.setSelectionRange(index, index);` to set the caret position.

And for your second question about removing the whole text when you keyup, You can use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method which will executed only once.,

```
$(this).one('keydown', function() {
      $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: but when I click into the input, so the cursor is not on the start, and when I type into the input a key, so I need everything except the key remove

Comment: @user984621: See my updated demo.. also edited your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/N9agf/5/

Comment: It's actually working just remove the clear part and don't use the demo (see console in demo)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [selectionStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Property/selectionStart) property of an input field to get the location of the caret and you can then check if this is behind the word 'Hello', by matching with the `value` of the field. You can then use [setSelectionRange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Method/setSelectionRange) to set the caret to a position. `setSelectionRange(0,0);` will set it to the beginning.

**Edit:** I just reread your questions and if you just want to delete all text when you type in it again, you can just use `select()` to select all text in the field. If you then start typing it deletes the selected text.

Comment: could you give me please an example? I try `$(this).select(); $(this).val('');`, but this is not the right way

Comment: Please put up a live example somewhere so we can understand what you want to do.

Comment: [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N9agf/3/) - when I click somewhere in the into the input, I need the cursor on the start and if I clicked into the input eg. on the key "a", so I would like everything into the input remove except "a"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/N9agf/4/ This moves the cursor to the beginning and makes the font red. And if you click **again** you want to have all letters removed except the one you clicked?